# Java Paint component not working

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

Here's the code, the square renders but will not move, even though it should render each loop. The problem appears to be in the Core class, in run()

```
    package com.game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Core implements Runnable{
    private static boolean running = true;
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100,100,600,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }





package com.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Paint extends JPanel{
    public static int x = 10;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.fillRect(x,10,100,100);
    }
}


        private static void start() {
            running = true;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Core());
            thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
            while(running){
                pane.add(p);
                pane.show();

                System.out.println(Paint.x);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
        }
    }
```

sorry if the code is annoying in any way, I'm not sure how I should format it...

Comment: There's something wrong with your code - too many curly braces...

Comment: Your code is posted wrong. It appears you posted one class accidentally inside of another.

Comment: You will also want to read the Swing tutorials as there are many things wrong with your code including trying to add components over and over again to a container.

Answer (score 3):

You're `while (running)` loop:

```
while(running){
   pane.add(p);
   pane.show();
   //....
}
```

is stepping on the Swing event thread and preventing this thread from doing its actions -- drawing the GUI and interacting with the user. Don't use a while (true) loop but instead use a Swing Timer if you want repeated behavior in a Swing application.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing `x` so why should it move?

Furthermore you are constantly (ten times a second) adding a Paint (your `JPanel` subclass) to the frame and showing it.

You probably want to add and show it once, perhaps in your main method (or somewhere better) and just call `repaint()` on it instead in that loop.

And please don't use `thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);` it rarely accomplishes anything, and probably not what you want.